# Is this power supply universal input voltage?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, step-down

I have this Playstation 2 power supply which was originally run at 110V input.
A fellow member of this forum suggested that there might be a good chance that
it could a universal input voltage and might work at 220V AC.

I have taken a look at the power supply board and I couldn't figure whether this
could be true. I'm posting the photo of my board and also the part numbers of
components that I was able to identify. I know for sure that the fuse is for 110V
but other components I'm not so sure. I tried searching for the transformer and
inductor coil datasheets but none exists. They are of Matsushita make.

Please help me determine whether this power supply is having universal input voltage
(aside from the fuse)

[image]

Comment: Not a chance…..

Comment: For such a power supply to be universal, not only does it need to support the higher voltage, but it also needs to output the same regulated voltage whether the input is 110 or 220… The fact they used a 110V fuse makes that quite unlikely IMHO.

Comment: No luck there unfortunately.

Comment: @winny It's ok. I was originally planning to use my ATX power supply like I previously mentioned.

Comment: It was a 50/50 shot.

Comment: Not with a 125V fuse it ain't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main bulk storage capacitor is rated at 220 volts DC: -

[image]

This means that the maximum sinewave RMS voltage that can be applied to the input power connector is 156 volts. This means that it is probably only recommended for supply voltages of 120 volts maximum.

Answer (score 11):

No, definitely not.

That 220 volt capacitor is a dead giveaway--and it'll really be dead if you hook this up to 230 volts AC! Rectified 230 volt mains is something like 325 volts, which would obliterate that capacitor in short order.

Comment: Really dead ... and yet still live...

Comment: @user_1818839 Sorry, what?

Comment: @Hearth "live" as in "having line voltage on it". Twere a joke.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably a 110V only model.

[image]

I think it very unlikely that they built a universal power supply, then printed some of them with fuse values for 125V.  If it were a universal power supply, the fuse would have to be rated for the highest expected line voltage (230VAC) rather than a lower voltage.